# 301 Redirect Scenario

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

so I have 2 websites that are identical. I am not wanting to remove my 2nd website. I need a 301 redirect which will redirect all visitors going to my second website to my 1st original website. Secondly, each page needs redirect to each corresponding page, not just to my home page. SO for example:

http://www.example2.com/awesome-page.php

Redirects To:

http://www.example1.com/awesome-page.php

I belive this needs to be done with a .htaccess file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using a custom 404 handler in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the web root of example2 place .htaccess with (I assume they are not physically in the same folder on the same server)

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example1.com/
```

ps: it redirects everything, not just the server's root.